# MomentJS timestamp parsing shows wrong date

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am using moment JS in my Angular project and I tried to parse a timestamp I got from server.

the problem is that moment outputs : `January 18, 1970 4:03 PM` for the timestamp : `1526636521`. which is not what I get form the online epoch converter. ( `Friday, May 18, 2018 9:42:01 AM`)

this is my moment call : `moment.utc(data.TimeStamp).format('LLL')` ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the number you are using is `number of seconds from 1970 Jan 1st`,

`moment.utc` takes in `number of milliseconds`,

So either use,

`moment.unix(1526636521).toString()`  // moment.unix takes in number of seconds
`moment.utc(1526636521000).toString()`  // Add three zeros to number.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`moment.unix`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) instead of [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)

> To create a moment from a Unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch), use `moment.unix(Number)`.

```js
var data = {
  TimeStamp: 1526636521
};
console.log( moment.unix(data.TimeStamp).format('LLL') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```