# React native date convert from int to date

Tags: reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I am new in react-native. I want to convert an `int` date to a formatted date.

The problem is it's always displaying the current date and not that date from the following integer: `1528101680`

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var newDate = moment(Date(1528101680)).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM');
console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MomentJS timestamp parsing shows wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409233/momentjs-timestamp-parsing-shows-wrong-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide time in milliseconds

```
var newDate = moment(new Date(1528101680 * 1000)).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM');
//                           -----------^^^^^^^------------
console.log(newDate);
```

```js
var newDate = moment(new Date(1528101680 * 1000)).format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM');

console.log(newDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me :)

Comment: @LemonKazi : glad to help

Comment: Or you can use [`moment.unix`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) _To create a moment from a Unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix Epoch)_ (see suggested duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
var newDate = moment(1528101680 * 1000).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM") 
console.log(newDate)
```

```js
var newDate = moment(1528101680 * 1000).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:MM") 
console.log(newDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```